# Is there a masked_max like masked_less in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

What is the equivalent of

```
masked_arr = np.ma.masked_max(arr, axis=(-1,-2))
```

to get

```
[[[False  True]
  [False False]]]

# or an equivalent with -- and max value in place
```

from

```
[[[ 0.5488135   0.71518937]
  [ 0.60276338  0.54488318]]]
```

I tried

```
np.ma.max(arr, axis=(-1,-2))
```

but it returns just a value like np.max, and not the mask. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you even need to use `np.ma` for that, you can just do

```
mask = np.isclose(x, x.max((-1, -2), keepdims = True))
```

remember to use `np.isclose` and not `==` for floats. However,

```
mask = x == x.max((-1, -2), keepdims = True)
```

works if you have integers or another type where `==` is safe.

Comment: ahhh, I see what you did there with `keepdims`; awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like `numpy.ma.masked_less`, there is a `numpy.ma.masked_greater`.

But you want `numpy.ma.masked_greater_equal`

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([
    [0.54881350, 0.71518937],
    [0.60276338, 0.54488318]
])

mask = numpy.ma.masked_greater_equal(x, x.max()).mask
print(mask)
```

and I get:

```
[[False  True]
 [False False]]
```